# When submitting my iOS app it tells me I cannot change my bundle id, but it isn't changed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

My bundle id within xcode matches the bundle id in itunesconnect perfectly, including capitalization.

I am trying to submit version 2 of the app and am getting this error, but the error does not specific what the bundle id is that i am submitting.

I have submitted a message through itunes connect on monday and have not received any emails, not even a notification letting me know they received it.

Any suggestions? Can the bundle id be changed dynamically when being submitted to the app store and I am not seeing it?

[image: bundle ids]

EDIT: FYI, apple transferred me to multiple admins who looked over my version 1 and version 2 and could not find the differences. This took place over a two week time period as I often had to email in asking them to get back to me like they promised they would. They finally told me to delete the old one and create a new one. Overall a very sad experience with apple. Not to mention losing users of the version 1 app and having to wait very long periods to have the new app approved.

Comment: Check the bundle id inside your ipa file, which is just a zip. The bundle id is in Whatever.app/Info.plist Something must go wrong in your package generation

Comment: I did, it is still correct. Inside Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier is still com.mycompany.MyApp

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the relevant portion of the info.plist file, as well as the bundle ID in the info view? I know sounds patronizing, but sometimes it just helps to have a second set of eyes on it.

Comment: double check whitespaces/special chars/0(zero) vs O(letter) also i dont thinks it is case sensitive, but check that anyway, the bundle id can not change when submitted, you basically just upload a zip

Comment: As soon as my ipad has a charge I will resubmit it and take screen shots of everything. Also, I think it is case sensitive because I have another app that has the same bundle id with different capitalization.

Comment: *I have another app that has the same bundle id with different capitalization* > two apps on same bundle identifier varying case sounds like a terrible idea to me, even if, yes, it is case sentitive

Comment: Added screenshots. Yes it was my first app and i had to create a new one when submitting the second versions. I didn't know at the time you couldnt delete apps.

Comment: Could it be that you picked the wrong application in the dropdown list? maybe the wrong bundle id is not the one you submit, but the expected one.

Comment: I dont think so because the new one is the only one that is ready for upload and the new one is MotocrossMatrixMX (they made me choose a different name)

Comment: Then sorry I'm out of ideas, triple-check, if you use git or any vcs (you do of course) look at xcodeproj history and... if nothing found, contact Apple support.

Comment: Yeah, i dont use any of that. I just zipped up the project as after submitting it and then unzipped it when i started version 2

Comment: And apple hasn't sent me an emails to even let me know they received my message.

Comment: Hi, I would focus on the first error. It looks like your app supports less devices than before. I see your app was for iPhone and it is still for iPhone (not universal), so that's good. But there must be a restriction in your project that reduces the number of devices. I would focus on that.

Comment: Adding a bit more to my previous comment. You could need vibration in this version. Then iPod would stop being supported, thus your app would be automatically rejected. Please read the link Apple provides.